# How do I keep a login modal from closing after the submit button is hit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a PHP website. When the user clicks login a JQuery Modal pops up and asks the user to login. After the submit button is clicked the box closes and the user is either logged in or invalid username/password is echo'd into the login modal but the box still closes. When you hit log in the modal pops up again with invalid username. I want the modal to stay open if the user does not log in correctly. Thank you!

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>Login</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body row">
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['login'])){                 
            $user_login = strip_tags(@$_POST['user_name']);
            $password_login = strip_tags(@$_POST['user_password']);
            $password_login = md5($password_login);
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user_login' AND password='$password_login' LIMIT 1");
            $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
            if($userCount == 1){
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $user_id = $row["id"];
                    $user_fname = $row["first_name"];
                    $user_lname = $row["last_name"];
                    $user_membersince = $row["date"];
                }
                $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user_login;
                $_SESSION['user_fname'] = $user_fname;
                $_SESSION['user_lname'] = $user_lname;
                $_SESSION['user_membersince'] = $user_membersince;

            }else {
                echo("invalid username/password");
            }
        }
    ?>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" placeholder="email address">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" type="password" name="user_password" placeholder="password">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class = "btn btn-warning" value="login"name="login">Login</button><a class = "btn btn-warning" data-dismiss = "modal">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The submit button causes a postback change type to button.

Comment: `Ajax` will help you out. Post your form using ajax

Comment: you have to close the form too, reaplce `<form action="" method="POST">` with `</form>` at bottom

Comment: the form was a typo, changing the button type to button just makes the submit button do nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax metod on click submit button.

```
$.ajax({   
   type: 'POST',   
   url: url,   
   data: $('#bob').serialize(),
   success: success,
   dataType: dataType 
});
```